# 2 different project working WCF

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, mvvm

Hello Stackoverflow users,

Some info:

For a project at school we had to create a battleship application using the MVVM pattern. The program is required to have a login system that works via XML. The game is somewhat finished and it works with fine with even including different difficulties of AIs. The next assignment we is to make the application WCF. We all worked in groups and the assignment tells us to play battleship against other groups from my class. We didn't use common interface for all the methods. All our implementations are completely different. I read some stuf about WCF and to be honest i don't have any clue where to start since everyone has different implementations of the game. I read some things about WCF and i get the most things.

Questions:

1. How do i login since the XML differs with other students?
2. What services do i need?
3. Where to begin?
4. Isn't this assignment too difficult? (since implementations differ allot)

I hope you can help me on my way.

Kind regards,

Winston

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As far as I understand, you should be able to cosume the WCF service created by other groups by adding a service reference to it or by creating a proxy. That way you will be able to interact with their service.